# Radon-Nikodym derivative of an atomic measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $u,v$ be two measures on the interval [0,3]: $u$ is the Dirac measure on 1 and $v$ is the Dirac measure on 2. Let $w = u+v$. Certainly, both $u$ and $v$ are absolutely-continuous with respect to $w$, so they have Radon-Nikodym derivatives with respect to $w$. What are these derivatives?

I understand that the derivative of e.g. $u$ is a function $f$ such that, for every subset $X\subseteq [0,3]$:

$$
u(X) = \int_{x\in X} f(x) d w
$$

However, I do not understand what "$d w$" means here, and in general, how can such integral be computed?

Comment: It should be clear that $f(x) = \mathbb{I}_1(x)$, where $\mathbb{I}_k$ is the indicator function for $k$.

Try splitting the integral into simple functions and use the definition of integration with respect to measure $w$ to see why this is obvious.

As to how the integral may be computed, we know that $u$ is the Dirac measure on $1$, so we know exactly how to compute it.